# how to access a file on the client's machine

Tags: javascript, file

I have a few clients that will be using my website, and I want each client to have their own "config" file (EX: location=1 for one computer, location=2 for another).  I want to do this using a file I place on the client's machine and then when they access the website the client looks on their own machine and figures out what to load based on what's in that file.  This file can be a CSV file, plain text file, or any other kind of file that it needs to be for this to work.

Looking online all I've seen is stuff with file uploader.  I don't want them to have to select the file, just have the file contents load and call a javascript function when they do.

Example of file

```
Location=1
AnswerToQuestion=42
```

and another file

```
Location=2
AnswerToQuestion=15
```

and my JS function

```
var setAnswerToQuestion = function(answer){
  locationConfig.setAnswer(answer)
}
```

Comment: How do you present the question and how does the user answer it?

Comment: @jcuenod I don't and they don't.  The system would already know the answer based on the answer in the file so the person using the webpage doesn't need to know the question's even being asked.

Comment: But where did the file come from? Are you emailing to people or are you using secret government equipment to inject it onto people's computers?

Comment: I am physically going to their location and putting a file on their machine with everything needed for them to run the app at that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). It's a persistent key/value system that the browser implements to keep data for your website/webapp.

**The Basic Principle:**

To set a variable:

```
localStorage.setItem('answer_1', '42');
```

To get a variable:

```
localStorage.getItem("answer_1");
```

I guess if you have lots of answers you would end up with an array/object something like this:

```
var answers = [42, 15];
```

**Towards a Solution:**

You could store and retrieve that by using `JSON.stringify`

```
localStorage.setItem('answers', JSON.stringify(answers));

var answers = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('answers'));
```

**Be Educated**

Smashing Magazine has a tutorial [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)
Dive into HTML5 has a tutorial [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: this doesn't work because it initializes everyone to Location:1 AnswerToQuestion: 42.   It needs to be localized to that system.

Comment: This doesn't initialize anything, this is what you use once you have an answer from them. The examples above are examples...

Comment: how do I get the answer from them?  that's what the file was providing

Comment: where does the question come from? Surely your UX doesn't involve them saving answers into a file on their computer...

Comment: @MattWestlake WebStorage API is "per origin" which means it's not shared between clients.

Comment: These are a set of pre-defined paramaters (like location#) that won't change as long as the computer is at that location.  We wanted to install a file so the client wouldn't have to answer questions like "Which location are you at?".  As soon as they hit the webpage, the page would look at the file and see it's location 1, and load the info based on that

Comment: Well if you have to populate a file on every machine, then just run an initialisation page in your webapp that allows you to set up all those variables. So your initial page stores them all and then the rest of your app just retrieves them.

Comment: again, that requires the user to input the data.  that is not the solution I'm looking for.  The whole purpose of this is so the client already knows what it's answers are and the user doesn't need to answer them himself.

Comment: I don't understand how you can expect there to be predefined values that are never set.

Comment: They are set in the file... I am physically going to their location and putting a file on their machine with everything needed for them to run the app at that location.

Comment: Go to their computer, open up the webpage and set the variables. You could even come with a text file prepopulated with JSON that you just copy into a form field that your app parses

Comment: that will not persist through someone closing the browser, or a system restart.

Comment: Yes it will, that's why I told you about localStorage. Go to the end of my answer and follow those links. Also note in the first line of my answer "persistent".

Comment: Everything I thought I knew about localStorage turned out to be false.... I thought it was just session data on the client.  Now that I know localStorage persists I can just do what you suggested and instead of "installing a file" just go there and set the info in the local storage.  Thanks for all your help and sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can't access files on local machines without using "file upload". You could store your config files on browser localstorage as:

```
var getConfigData = function() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('config'));
}

var saveConfigData = function(config) {
    localStorage.setItem('config', JSON.stringify(config));
}

var addDataToConfig = function(key, value) {
    var config = getConfigData();
    config[key] = value;
    saveConfigData(config);
}

var config = {
    Location: 1,
    AnswerToQuestion: 42
};

// save new config
saveConfigData(config);

// add new data to config
addDataToConfig('name', 'John Doe');
```

Comment: this doesn't work because it initializes everyone to Location:1 AnswerToQuestion: 42.   It needs to be localized to that system.

Comment: Yes, I know @MattWestlake, it's only an example to show you how to store data in user browser. when a usser will login on your page then you could store individual data.

Comment: @JoseMato Do you know that you can set localStorage using `localStorage['key'] = value`?

Comment: thanks @jcuenod I missed call saveConfigData. fixed!

Comment: the issue wasn't the localStorage.  the issue is getting the inital information from each client (when each client has their own information).

Comment: Ok, to get the "initial information" the first time you need that the user will be log in, then you could retrieve the individual data using an ajax call and finally store it on local storage.

Comment: I don't want to use authentication without the need for authorization.  I just want a file with an identifier on it so the client doesn't have to enter any data or login to see the information relative to their location (building # not geoLocation)